# Skipping a line and reading another line in shell script while loop

Tags: shell, while-loop

i have a code which reads a file line by line using a while loop. Inside the while loop, i have certain conditions. Is there a way using which i can skip the current line and read the next line based upon the condition ? Let me be precise:

```
while read Line
do
    //some sample conditions
    a=$Line
    if [ "a" == "b" ]
        //i want to go to the next line from this point. 
done < **inputfile**
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `continue` http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-continue-in-bash-loop/

Comment: Thanks a bunch scibuff ! Sorry for the late reply ! Your solution worked !

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
while read Line
do
    # some sample conditions
    a=$Line
    if [ "$a" == "$b" ] # I assume this is not "a" == "b"
        # i want to go to the next line from this point. 
        read Line
        a=$Line
done < **inputfile**
```

Comment: the if condition may be anything. What i want is, based upon the condition, file reading should start from the next line and immediately after do. The script you gave will read the next line, but it will be reflected only for lines after the condition .What i want is , based on the condition, the next line should be read and the operations should start from the beginning.

Comment: If I get your comment right, scibuff's answer is what you are looking for. Could you please take some time to accept it or comment why that is not the answer you are looking for ?